# R: Removing Text using gsub in loop

Tags: r, regex, loops, gsub

I'm trying to parse and clean up a string in a column named Tab in a dataframe named df3 in R. Here is my solution adopting the gsub() function in R.

```
df3$Tab <- gsub(".*from","",df3$Tab)
df3$Tab <- gsub(".*FROM","",df3$Tab)
df3$Tab <- gsub("where.*","",df3$Tab)
df3$Tab <- gsub("WHERE.*","",df3$Tab)
```

basically I'd like to remove all before and up to "FROM" as well as everything behind "WHERE".
This solution works but I'd like to write down a loop, but when I do this:

```
df3$Tab <- for (i in seq_along(df3$Tab)){
  df3$Tab <- gsub(".*from","",df3$Tab)
  df3$Tab <- gsub(".*FROM","",df3$Tab)
  df3$Tab <- gsub("where.*","",df3$Tab)
  df3$Tab <- gsub("WHERE.*","",df3$Tab)
  break
}
```

I completely delete the df3$Tab column. Is the anybody that can explain me where I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: The `seq_along` of vector implies you are looping over the rows of the data while assinging  on the whole column.  Instead your code would be `for(i in 1:4)` as there are only 4 steps.  Also, this may not require 4 steps i..e you can use `ignore.case = TRUE` - `df$Tab <- gsub("(.*from)|(where.*)", "", df3$Tab, ignore.case = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wondering why you are using a loop at all. This one-liner should work as well:

```
df3$Tab <- gsub("(?i)(where.*|.*from)", "",df3$Tab)
```

- `(?i)`: a flag to make the regex case-insensitive
- `(where.*|.*from)`: an alternation group matching both (i) literal `where` followed by anything zero or more times and (ii) literal `from` preceded by anything zero or more times

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm new in R! your solution is perfect!

Comment: same as `df3$Tab <- gsub("where.*|.*from", "",df3$Tab, TRUE)`